# Display menu items as articles in Joomla

Tags: joomla

I have created a Menu with the following structure:

Menu

```
Main Item 1
Main Item 2
    SubItem1 (show category1 as blog)
    SubItem2 (show category2 as blog)
    SubItem3 (show category3 as blog)
Main Item 3
```

When selecting Main Item 2, I would like to show a page with a list of the menu items that contains Main Item 2, something like a magazine cover, where every item appears with an image and a description. Clicking on the image or title would link to the actual menu SubItemX.

I think what I'm trying to do is to use Menu Items as articles, so they can be used as articles in other pages.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can find some great menu modules in the Joomla Extensions Directory at http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/structure-a-navigation/menu-systems

In Module Manager, you can specify a custom module position such as "mymenu" or similar.

You can include the module in the article using `{loadposition mymenu}`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by making the Main Item 2 link to an article. This article will be styled as you want it, a magazine cover. For example inside this article you will have headers with the names of the SubItems that will link to these items. Trying anything else will probably limit you in terms of design.